# TimescaleDB continuous aggregates count DISTINCT

Tags: timescaledb

Say I have a simple hypertable such as

| device_id | value1 | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 2022-04-04 10:10 |
| 2 | 431 | 2022-04-04 10:53 |
| 1 | 321 | 2022-04-04 10:12 |

And I then create a continuous aggregate with a time bucket width of 1 hour for example.
How would I keep a count of the DISTINCT device ids that reported in for each hour? For example in this case the result would be 2 devices for the timestamp *2022-04-04 10:00*

I effectively want something like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW agg_hourly_devices WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS
SELECT sum(value1) as value1,
       time_bucket('1h', timestamp) as timestamp,
       count(distinct(device_id)) as device_count
FROM devices
GROUP BY time_bucket('1h', timestamp)
```

But TimescaleDB does not allow the use of DISTINCT on continuous aggregates, therefore this definition is invalid. Any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by device_id and then count the amount of values.

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW agg_hourly_devices 
WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS
    SELECT SUM(value1) AS myValue,
           time_bucket('1h', "timestamp") AS bucket_time,
           COUNT(value1) AS device_count
    FROM devices
    GROUP BY bucket_time, device_id
    ORDER BY bucket_time, device_id
```

Comment: This was indeed the only way I found to get around it but it's not exactly what I want. I would still need to do a second aggregation to get results independent of device_id.